# Why is it that when I hard code a font-size for an element it resizes responsively in the browser, and why doesn't this happen in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design, scaling

I have some header text in a project that resizes even if the font size is hardcoded in pixels.

```
<h1 style="font-size:200px;">Test</h1>
```

Furthermore, I have been trying to port the project to Angular, where this text does not scale.

I was wondering why the text scales in plain HTML, and what could be done to make it scale in Angular?

Comment: Hey! You're setting an absolute size for the font. The reason why this is probably working outside of angular is because you may have a CSS media query that will over write that value. You could use `rem` as a unit or creating media query on your component css.

Comment: @MrRobot where would this CSS media query come from. I've noticed that on a blank HTML page with only the above code I still get the resizing?

Comment: You ask 'why the text scales in plain HTML' - it doesn't. Are you talking about zooming rather than resizing?

Comment: @NazarViznytsya can you please post the entire page on your question? I think we may be talking about 2 different things.

Comment: I've tried with only the presented code, and still notice scaling when I select the mobile options on Chrome DevTools